# resizing an image using matlab GUI

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-guide

I'm trying to resize an image using MATLAB GUI. Here is the resize button callback

```
global im
prompt = {'Enter rate of increase/decrease:'};
dlg_title = 'Resize';
num_lines = 1;
sr = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines);
sr = str2double(sr);
ims=im;
ims=imresize(ims,sr);
axes(handles.frame);
imshow(ims);
```

My problem is that the axes don't scale to fit new image size.  I mean, when I enter value between 0 and 1, the image dimensions (axes dimensions) don't decrease so the image stretches to fit the axes, distorting the image.

The same thing happens when I enter a value >1.

Comment: If you would show the result you get, and the one you want, it would be helpful.

Comment: no sir ): the same problem ... any other ideas please

Comment: as you know if I enter sr=0.5 the image dimensions will decrease to half . My problem is the axes dimensions don't decrease to half too